react-native-reanimated: Failed to notify project evaluation listener
How do I resolve this error: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Gradle Wrapper Properties:


distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists



And, android/build.gradle


buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}...



